# How to introduce class system similar to ExtJs

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I was trying to solve this looking at the ExtJs code, but I don't get the magic that is happening there.

I'd like to recreate the Ext class behaviour, which can be stripped to two basic functions :

- define
- create

Define is used to reserve a namespace for the new class and save reference to class constructor (at least my debugging indicates this). Sample usage : `Ext.define('Foo', {param: 1})`;

Create is used to instantiate the class which simply returns new object instance.

Now I wonder what should be stored in the 'define' step, because afaik constructor itself is not enough to instantiate an object ? (or am I wrong)

Has anyone seen any references to materials covering topic of class systems in javascript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Douglas Crockford has a good article about classical inheritance in JavaScript: http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html

Some pseudocode that I think works similar to what Sencha has in their Ext (although I think that you should take a look at proper implementation in link above first):

```
//define takes class name (string) and definition(object)
//definition in this case should have a method called constructor()

var classes = {};


classes.define = function(className, definition){
    classes[className] = definition;
}

//call create with class name and it will make a new class using that constructor
classes.create = function(className){
   return new classes[className].apply(this);
}

classes.define('Hello',{name: "Pi" , game : "Tennis"});

console.log(classes);

classes.create('Hello');
```

Comment: Is Ext an "an awful piece of software" because of the design of their class system?

Comment: Can you share why you dislike the sencha class system? It makes things like inheritance, mixins, overwrites pretty easy.

Comment: Because it's a hack. JavaScript is very powerful language and can do all those things. But instead of learning how to do them properly in prototype-based functional language, which JS is, they just hacked together their own system.

Comment: @hopper, no to be fair I don't like that framework for many reasons. poluting the dom with ext-genXXX, their grid, which has way too many DOM nodes than necessary, the methods ext.get and ext.query, which should be one method, but instead are two (and ext.fly too), the fact that I can't use the same methods on stuff rerurned from ext.get and ext.query, and so on... I do understand where they are coming from and what they are trying to do, I just don't approve of it.

Comment: I have updated the answer, because "awful piece of software" was an exaggeration, but I still think that hey have a lot of bad practices.

Comment: I'm totally with you regarding the DOM pollution and other things. I just think the class system is actually it's biggest strength. Sure you can hand craft all those things. But JavaScript is pretty flexible, powerful, yet complicated in this aspect. I think they actually did a great job in abstracting those things array.

Comment: Btw, class definitions coming in ES 6 do exactly the same thing what Sencha and other frameworks already do today. They put syntactic sugar on top of what we currently already have but needs more manual plumbing.